# Sending MIDI messages using Python (on Ubuntu)

Tags: python, midi

I am trying to send a basic MIDI message to a synthesizer, using Python.

I know that the PC-Synthesizer link is functional because the Rosegarden application can be configured to play MIDI files on the device, when the MIDI output is set to 'DigitalKBD 20:0' port.

I have discovered this Python library ([MIDO](http://mido.readthedocs.org/)) and installed it. The good news is that the external MIDI device is recognized and available in the port list. Unfortunately the simple note-on test does not trigger any sound on the device. Here is the code I tried:

Using PortMidi (this is the default for MIDO):

```
>>> import mido
>>> output = mido.open_output('DigitalKBD MIDI 1')
>>> output.send(mido.Message('note_on', note=60, velocity=64))
```

Using RtMidi:

```
>>> import mido
>>> rtmidi = mido.Backend('mido.backends.rtmidi')
>>> output = rtmidi.open_output('DigitalKBD 20:0')
>>> output.send(mido.Message('note_on', note=60, velocity=64))
```

In both cases, there is no sound coming from the synthesizer whatsoever.

Please, can I get advice how to fix the code (or setup) so that the instrument receives and interprets the messages correctly?

Comment: Run `aseqdump`, play to that port, and check if anything arrives.

Comment: mido might be sending on a different MIDI channel. Verify which MIDI channel the synthesizer is listening for notes and try setting explicitly on `mido.Message` the `channel` field accordingly.

Comment: This might not be the forum for your question because it isn't a python language specific question. It is an API, installation, library compatiblity  or environment issue.  Have you reviewed the documentation for the library?

Comment: How about volume and duration?

Comment: Does `mido.get_output_names()` list the name of your device as an available output? Try using the exact string returned by that function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, well, I got the MIDI in/out working, by creating a small script that echoes whatever is played on the keyboard, with certain delay:

```
import mido
import time
from collections import deque

print mido.get_output_names() # To list the output ports
print mido.get_input_names() # To list the input ports

inport = mido.open_input('DigitalKBD MIDI 1')
outport = mido.open_output('DigitalKBD MIDI 1')

msglog = deque()
echo_delay = 2

while True:
    while inport.pending():
        msg = inport.receive()
        if msg.type != "clock":
            print msg
            msglog.append({"msg": msg, "due": time.time() + echo_delay})
    while len(msglog) > 0 and msglog[0]["due"] <= time.time():
        outport.send(msglog.popleft()["msg"])
```

This script works very well, so I had opportunity to walk carefully back to see why my initial test was unsuccessful. Turns out, for the output messages to be received, the input port also has to be opened. Don't know the reason why, but this is the simplest code that works:

```
import mido
inport = mido.open_input('DigitalKBD MIDI 1')
outport = mido.open_output('DigitalKBD MIDI 1')
outport.send(mido.Message('note_on', note=72))
```

What's more, if the python is exited immediately after running the above code, it might happen that MIDO did not manage to send the message, so no sound will be played. Give it some time to wrap up.

Comment: OSError: unknown port 'DigitalKBD MIDI 1'

Comment: @OzanKurt print the output and input names using the code above (needs slight syntax update for Python 3), to see what input/output ports are detected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a sleep to your call, right after you send the message to the output.

I have added a simple sleep right after the message of 1s and the tone play just fine

Comment: When using rtmidi, I had to do a similar thing. Instead of using a sleep, you can also have a loop, just as in the example above where the keyboard is echoed.In my case, I just a keylistener