# Interfacing MIDI device (Akai LPD8 mk2) from Python - works for reading but not sending

Tags: python, midi

## Preface

I have an [Akai LPD8 mk2](https://www.akaipro.com/lpd8-mk2) which I would like to interface from Python.

There are two projects that (I believe) provide interfaces for the predecessor (mk1):

- https://github.com/zetof/LPD8
- https://github.com/DrLuke/python-lpd8

I found I needed to make a few small changes to get the reading to work with these libs (*example below, not sure how relevant this is and it could easily be because I misunderstand something).

However, no matter what I tried, I could not get the sending to the device to work. Specifically, changing the state (on/off) of the pads of the device from Python. This state is indicated by the color of the pads' lighting.

## Question

A minimal example of what I thought should work is the following:

With the very nice [mido](https://mido.readthedocs.io) library, I would like to read a few state changes of the pads. Then send them back with a small delay (similar idea here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29501455/655404):

```py
from time import sleep
import mido


def get_ioport_name(search):
    # see footnote **
    names = mido.get_ioport_names()
    names = set(n for n in names if search in n)
    assert len(names) == 1
    return names.pop()

def get_messages(port):
    return list(port.iter_pending())


name = get_ioport_name("LPD8")
port = mido.open_ioport(name) # see footnote ***

# ensure that there are no messages in the queue
get_messages(port)

#pause
input("Press a few pads, then press Enter to continue...")

msgs = get_messages(port)
print(f"Recorded these messages:\n{msgs}\n")

print("Echoing these messages:")
for m in msgs:
    print(m)
    port.send(m)
    sleep(1)
```

This runs and gives no error messages. However, the expected color changes on the pads do **not** happen.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have tried with different [backends](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/index.html) for mido (rtmidi, portmidi, pygame) as well as using [rtmidi](https://pypi.org/project/python-rtmidi/) directly, all with the same result.

## Footnotes

#### *Example for changes needed:

I had to change the constant's block here https://github.com/zetof/LPD8/blob/master/lpd8/lpd8.py#L16 to:

```py
    NOTE_ON = 144+9
    NOTE_OFF = 128+9
    CTRL = 176
    PGM_CHG = 192+9
```

#### **Port names

`names = mido.get_ioport_names()` gives:

```py
['Midi Through:Midi Through Port-0 14:0',
 'LPD8 mk2:LPD8 mk2 MIDI 1 20:0',
 'Midi Through:Midi Through Port-0 14:0',
 'LPD8 mk2:LPD8 mk2 MIDI 1 20:0']
```

and `set(names)` gives:

```py
{'LPD8 mk2:LPD8 mk2 MIDI 1 20:0', 'Midi Through:Midi Through Port-0 14:0'}
```

The result is also the same for `mido.get_input_names()` and `mido.get_output_names()`.

#### ***Ports in mido

From what I understand mido has three port classes:

```py
open_input()  # only receive
open_output() # only send
open_ioport() # both (and what I used above)
```

If I change from ioport to using an input/output pair, the result is the same:

```py
port_in = mido.open_input(name)
port_out = mido.open_output(name)

# ensure that there are no messages in the queue
get_messages(port_in)

#pause
input("Press a few pads, then press Enter to continue...")

msgs = get_messages(port_in)
print(f"Recorded these messages:\n{msgs}\n")

print("Echoing these messages:")
for m in msgs:
    print(m)
    port_out.send(m)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is the result of just `mido.get_ioport_names()`?
I don't know anything about this lib but I can see you are only using 1 element in this list, and I also know MIDI usually has an IN port and an OUT port.

Comment: @PeacefulJames I added the information you asked for to the question. I believe mido deals with this correctly if one uses ioport. The available names for ioports, inputs and ouputs are all the same four items with two duplicates.